# Connect cp2102 or FTDI to Android 4.x

Tags: android

I want to connect a custom device with cp2102 to Android powered tablet. I connect it in VCP mode (using PID EA60) and use JavaComm to find it,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Enumeration <CommPortIdentifier> ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

while (ports.hasMoreElements())
{
    final CommPortIdentifier port = ports.nextElement();
    Log.d(null, port.toString());
}
```

but I never enter the loop.

I have an option to use FTDI instead of silabs. They have a variant of using their D2xx dll through JNI. I followed their guide but I have a memory crash (signal something and heap corrupted message in LogCat), when I connect ft232r and try to determine the number of connected devices. When I unplug the device from the tablet, the same code (their sample code) works just fine, returning zero, which is true.

When I use JavaComm with FTDI the result is the same as with cp2102: the loop is not entered.

I guess I miss something or do something wrong.

If I'm to use, say, usb-mode instead of VCP, I'm ready to start searching, I just need a hint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if your Android kernel supports CP2102? In my SL101, FTDI is supported but CP2102 is not. You can check that from kernel logs after plugging the device. FTDI device has bad permissions by default, though.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that the CP210x driver is not enabled in the Android kernel by default. So you will either need to build this driver in to your kernel to get the tty access and ability to use JavaComm.

The other option is to use the [USB Host functionality](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) and access your CP210x directly with [it's API](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN571.pdf).